# Problem with ideal LED diode with much higher voltage than its minimum

Tags: led, diodes

I have an ideal LED diode with Vγ (minimum voltage)= 0.7 V that supports a maximum current of 5 mA. And I want to connect the diode and use it directly polarized with a voltage source with value Vg = 5 V, but my question is what problem can occur if we connect the diode directly to the voltage source?

As far as I know, the diode is supposed to not work if voltage is less than 0.7 and work as a short if is higher so it should work fine. But I think that this problem wants me to answer something like: The LED will burn. So what will happen?

Comment: diodes have an exponential increase of current, as the voltage is linearly increased. Ultimately the current is limited by internal bulk silicon doping conductivity. Non-LEDs will have approximately 1mA at 0.6 volts, 10 mA at 0.66volts, 100mA (0.1 amp) at 0.72 volts, etc. Notice the current increases 10X for each 0.06 volt forward drop voltage increase. Can  you get lower currents? yes. Expect about 0.1mA (100 microAmps) at 0.6 - 0.06v, expect 0.01mA (10uA) at 0.6 - 2*0.06; expect 1microAmp at 0.6 - 3*0.06volts

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sure you can see that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. The information can be readily found by internet searches and self-learning, which is the goal of the question you were set (as described in your question).

Comment: I beg to differ from other commenters who think you haven't shown enough efforts. This is known and acknowledged bitter experience faced by perhaps every stackexchange newbie( not just on ee.se but on every se site) , which is reported to have adversely affected site's audience. I hope you'll hang in...

Comment: I understand that it may seem that I have not shown enough effort and that all I want is to have my exercise resolved. But it is not so, before asking I have reviewed my notes, I have searched for information on the internet and in books, but I have not found something as concrete as what I am asked, so I ask for help, since it is the first time I have faced to this kind of problems. I am against questions like "do my homework" and I have expressed this in other communities in which I participate.

Comment: That's great to hear, Fran. Please put what you have found so far in your question and that will be apparent to the potential answerers who come here to help people. But how will they understand how much you know and will they want to start from the very beginning? @Deep comment is supportive but misguided: there is a clear and simple path to writing a good question and getting the most out of this site. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: You do **not** have an "ideal LED diode."  An ideal diode is either a [non-existent model](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Ideal-diode.php) or a [circuit that (almost) mimics](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/articles/simple-inexpensive-ideal-diode-mosfet-circuits.817/) the function of an ideal diode.

Comment: LED = light emitting diode.  LED diode = light emitting diode diode.  This message brought to you by the department of redundancies department.

Comment: I am a self - student and this is a problem that I saw on an exam page, I have adapted the statement so that it was not a copy and paste, so I have nothing. This is the original statement in case you are interested (translated from Spanish):

We have an ideal LED diode with Vγ = 0’7 V that supports a maximum current of 5 mA. We want to connect the diode and use it directly polarized with a voltage source with value Vg = 5 V.

(a) What problem can occur if we connect the diode directly to the voltage source?

Comment: And I said "problem wants me to answer something like: The LED will burn." Because of the part 

(b) To solve the problem in the previous section, they tell us that we can add a resistance between the diode and the source. Indicate if we have to add this resistance in series or in parallel with the diode and what its value has to be.

Comment: The answer to what problem can occur is current will exeed 5mA.

Answer (score 1):

Silicon diodes drop about 0.7V.  LEDs are around 1.5 to 3.2V, depending on their color.

If we assume an ideal diode, then if you connect it to an ideal 5V supply, then an infinite current will flow.  Infinite currents are not generally considered a good thing.

In the real World, where no component is ideal, it may go pop, or give off smoke, or just go black inside.  Either way, it won't work for very long.

Answer (score -1):

You got it right till,
"... and work as a short if (Voltage) is higher (than 0.7V)"
but not when you said
"so it should work fine".

LED (in which D itself stends for 'Diode', so no need to write LED Diode, writing so will probably attract visible anger from every good EE) works as a 'closed switch' for voltages greater than threshold is just "somewhat" correct statement, in fact current increases exponentially with *voltage across diode*. Voltage drop across on diode is around 0.7V. (in case of LED, it is not 0.7V to be precise but varies depending mainly on color of LED).

When diodes are used in power electronics applications where voltage levels encountered are so high that 0.7V  drop is negligible and we regard diode as a closed switch.

However, whether it's diode or LED, when we say that it is behaving as closed switch, it should be kept in mind that these switches have "continuous current rating" which should not be exceeded. If they're acting like closed switches, and you don't connect anything in series (usually resistor) with them to limit the current, you'd effectively short the voltage source through that closed switch, causing too large current to flow through LED. LED would be usually 'weakest link' in the circuit and it'll sacrifice itself.